# Implementing a "Reload" Function

Tags: c++

I'm currently at a loss as to how to implement a function to my Weapon class for reloading.

What my program is supposed to do (for learning purposes) is have an abstract Weapon class that has two classes deriving from it, Sword and Crossbow. The Sword class works as its supposed to, and therefore needs to toying with. However, the Crossbow class needs to detect whether its loaded or not, and if it is not loaded it will then load it and fire it.

For an example, here is the demo output my teacher gave to the class: (this is how it is supposed to look)

Crossbow inflicts 15 damage points.

Sword inflicts 10 damage points.

Crossbow not loaded!

Crossbow inflicts 15 damage points.

Optimistically speaking, I'd like to have it look similar.

**Please, no direct answers. This is homework and I'd really like to learn this. I'm looking for points in the right direction.**

## Weapon.h

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Weapon
{
public:
    Weapon(int damage = 0);
    virtual void Attack() const = 0;

protected:
    int m_Damage;
};

Weapon::Weapon(int damage) : m_Damage(damage)
{}

class Sword : public Weapon
{
public:
    Sword(int damage = 10);
    virtual void Attack() const;
};

Sword::Sword(int damage): Weapon(damage)
{}

void Sword::Attack() const
{
    cout << "The sword hits for " << m_Damage << " points of damage" << endl;
}

class Crossbow : public Weapon
{
public:
    Crossbow(int damage = 20);
    virtual void Attack() const;
            void Reload() const;
};

Crossbow::Crossbow(int damage) : Weapon(damage)
{}

void Crossbow::Attack() const
{
cout << "The crossbow hits for " << m_Damage << " points of damage" << endl;
}

void Crossbow::Reload() const
{
cout << "Crossbow not loaded! Please reload" << endl;
}
```

Comment: ahem... that's way too much help. I think it's enough to say that `Crossbow` has some internal state, and since one of the main features of OO is encapsulation, it should be pretty obvious where to store this state...

Comment: You could also create an Reloadable interface, and implement it only in those classes that need it.

Comment: @HanletEscaño: c++ doesn't have interfaces. but a subclass or mutliple inheritance(brrr) can do the job.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, you can definitely have interfaces in c++.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I will delete my comment and replace it with a small hint: you need a bool in your Crossbow class.

Comment: @HanletEscaño I think that's a bit overkill for this.

Comment: @HanletEscaño Don't be sad! Now I feel bad :( It's an excellent solution!

Comment: @NeilKirk haha don't feel bad, you are totally right. No need to complicate things, especially if the OP is still learning, and probably not familiar with the concept. :) You are a cool guy.

Comment: I'm honestly not entirely sure what to do at this point. I had a similar idea to what was said below by BigTailWolf and naturally it did not work due to my `Attack` function being const.

Comment: Perhaps the attack function can no longer be const. That is ok. Using a weapon can change its state in many ways (ammo, durability..)

Comment: Yeah I changed my pure virtual const function to just a regular ole pure virtual function and it works perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to add field "ammo" in your Base class. Sword does not have the concept "ammo". Add it in your Crossbow class. It can be a bool type as flag.

You can assume it's not loaded while creating a Crossbow, so in the constructor initial list, you just add loaded(false)

Then you should change your "attack" by checking if loaded first. If not loaded, reload first
kind of reload function:

```
void Crossbow::reload() {
    if ( !loaded ) {
        cout << "Crossbow loading ..." << endl;
        loaded = true;
    }
    cout << "Crossbow reloaded" << endl;
}

void Crossbow::attack() {
    if ( !loaded ) {
        cout << "Crossbow not loaded! Please reload" << endl;
        reload();
    }
    cout << "The crossbow hits for " << m_Damage << " points of damage" << endl;
    loaded = false;
}
```

For doing this, your attack and reload cannot be const because there is a value changed in the function.

Now you can either call reload() for just reloading or just call attack() regardless of whether it's loaded or not.

Comment: Although this goes against my saying "Please no direct answers", this did confirm the thought I already had in my head.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it suits you, but try to add a field to `Weapon` called something like `ammo`. The constructors will then set it to the required amount, and the crossbow's `Attack` should have to check if there is any ammo left in the quiver or not. If not, set the value of `ammo` to the original. This is really simple. For the `Sword`, simply, don't check the ammo! :)

Also note, that it is a bad practice and only a temporary fix until you better understand these concepts. The correct way would be creating a new class that inherits from `Weapon` and this class will be inherited by the weapons that have ammo.

Hope I helped, and have fun learning C++ ! :)

Comment: I'd disagree .. adding a field to the base class that is superfluous to some of the derived classes is not the best thing to do.  IMHO there needs to be another level of abstraction for weapons that require ammo.  Likewise the sword could also derive from something that says it is an edged weapon (and hence can cut) to differentiate it from a club

Comment: Yes, indeed it is bad practice. But the OP is a learner and adding another layer of depth may be an overkill for him. This is the sole reason I wrote my answer so.

Comment: This is a red herring. The problem isn't about ammo (yet).

Comment: @LeventeKurusa Teaching someone a bad practice because they are a just a learner is a pretty bad excuse.  If you are going to do that you need to point out that it is a bad practice and what the consequences of it are.  Otherwise how is the learner supposed to learn?